# Why do calls from our Google Cloud Function deployed in europe-west6 (Zürich) originate from an US located IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, google-cloud-functions

We have a Google Cloud Function deployed in europe-west6 (Zürich), which makes HTTP calls to an API. In our server logs these HTTP calls originate from the IP address 35.203.247.36, which is showing the US as the origin. I was expecting a source IP address from Switzerland. This causes some issues with geoblocking configurations.

I found this related thread https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72263361#comment91, which states this should work as expected, but the linked IP ranges seem to differ from our observation:

```
  {
    "ipv4Prefix": "34.65.0.0/16",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "34.104.110.0/23",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "34.124.46.0/23",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "35.216.128.0/17",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "35.220.44.0/24",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "35.235.216.0/21",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "35.242.44.0/24",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }, {
    "ipv6Prefix": "2600:1900:4160::/44",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "europe-west6"
  }
```

Why do our API calls not originate from one of these IP ranges?

Comment: Why do you believe it shows US origin?

Comment: Requests from this IP were blocked by our firewall until we deactivated geoblocking for the US. It also shows US as the location in various other IP tracking services, for example, here: https://ipinfo.io/AS396982/35.200.0.0/14-35.203.244.0/22

Comment: I would guess this is due to outdated databases. Note that a looking glass from HE.net shows a route over a Swiss internet exchange, suggesting that it's indeed located in Switzerland. Geo-blocking based on IP is not an exact science, and with the current shortage of IPv4 addresses, Google may have to move IP-blocks frequently to accommodate customers. It should be pretty easy to rule out the IP's being in USA: if ping time is <40ms, it's in not trans-atlantic traffic.

Comment: IP-addresses are not street addresses and IP to location databases are therefore not 100% reliable. Often the location that will associated with all IP addresses “owned” by a corporation will be that of the company’s corporate headquarter, Mountain View California in the case of Google, rather than a more accurate location better representing the actual physical location of the infrastructure using that IP-address

Comment: Thanks for the information, I guess that explains US showing as the location. What confuses me is that the mentioned IP address 35.203.247.36 is not part of Google's IP range table and geofeed: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json, http://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud_geofeed (or have I overlooked something?)

Comment: check other api's like whatsmyip, also instrument some minimal tracert data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So expanding on some of the comments:

- When you look at the actual routing of traffic to that IP , for example with a looking glass from https://he.net , that shows a route over a Swiss internet exchange, suggesting that the IP-address is indeed located in Switzerland.
- The observed IP-address, `35.203.247.36` is part of a large range       35.192.0.0 - 35.207.255.255 (35.192.0.0/12) that Google has assigned for use by Google Cloud customers.  Google self publishes a geolocation feed on http://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud_geofeed  ([JSON version](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json) ) but that feed does not include every subnet they have created and no entry for a subnet containing `35.203.247.36` with a more specific region or location exists.

  In the absence that more specific record  it is likely that your
  GeoLocation database therefore used Mountain View, California, US as that is
  the address of record in the [whois
  data](https://ipinfo.io/AS396982/35.200.0.0/14-35.203.244.0/22).
- An IP-address represents a network location and not a longitude/ latitude or street address.
  *Although often a usable approximation, the actual reliability and accuracy of the location assigned to an IP-address varies between almost city block accurate and complete fiction.*

  Consider that routing protocols allow the owner/operator to almost instantly adjust their internal subnetting and change
  where on the internet a particular IP-address (range/subnet) can be
  used. Where a particular IP-address (range) is used today does not
  have to be the same place  where it
  will be used tomorrow. And then there's also [anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) in which a *single IP-address is shared by servers in multiple locations*.

  Despite accuracy/completeness claims by IP GeoLocation providers the street address that many such databases will use for an IP-address from corporate IP-address range(s) will frequently  *default to the street address found in the [Whois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) record*. That address is often an corporate headquarters, not an datacenter street address nor for example an (international) branche office location where (after internal subnetting) part of IP-address space is actually assigned and used.

  And even providers to do offer you an accuracy indication (like for instance how [Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-web-services-demo) shows an accuracy radius of a `1000 km` for 35.203.247.36 versus `20 km` for 45.79.90.233 and only 5 km for the indeed accurate location of my home IP-addresses ) that uncertainty or  (lack of) accuracy subtlety gets completely removed  once their IP location data gets flattened into location based block and allow lists.

---

In general when you can, use the IP-addresses of known and trusted clients in your allow lists rather than granting  access based on IP GeoLocation data.

It is possible to [associate a static IP](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip) with your Google cloud function to facilitate that:

> 1. Route your function's egress through your VPC network.
> 2. Set up Cloud NAT and specify a static IP address.

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed reply! "use the IP-addresses of known and trusted clients in your allow lists".. that's kind of difficult with cloud providers which don't publish all of their IP ranges publicly, like in this case, and which can change their IPs from one day to the next. Do you have a recommendation for these?

Comment: How to ensure that your cloud function egress traffic uses a static IP rather than a random one is a different question but see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip